# How to open a dataset of ".m" in R

Tags: r, matlab

I want to import a *Matlab* data set into R. I'm getting the following error:

```
Error in file(con, open = "rb") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(con, open = "rb") :
  cannot open file 'data.mat': No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use R.matlab package. R will read .mat files.
Give it a go but I suspect you need to do something like `save('yourMfile.mat')`in Matlab.
Then in R

```
library(R.matlab)
readMat("../input/yourMfile.mat")
```